# How to span the inner container of the Emoji-mart component in angular 100% of the containing div

Tags: css, angular

I have a div which contains the emoji-mart component.
When i add an inline style of "width:100%;" to the emoji-mart component, the :host of the emoji mart truly spans the entire width but the actual container containing the emojis and with a border radius doesn't move. How can i make it also span 100% of the width?

Comment: it's really difficult to diagnose issues with css when you haven't provided any of the code or any example of what the section looks like vs what you are expecting.

Comment: A guess: by finding the correct css-selector for the element and giving it 100% also. You can experiment with the css in the developer tools. If the component is in some library you can still have this css in your global css-file, but of course not inline. But impossible to say without more info

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem... in the emoji mart component i had to include a
style property with the square brackets in order to bind my css properties with that of the emoji mart component

<emoji-mart [style]="{ width: 'unset' }">